# Determine if calculation between 2 date time values is < 72 Hours in excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

So I'm comparing a booked datetime values between two appointments, and I want to create a flag against each record where the time difference is less than 72 hours.

Calculating the difference in hours is easy using a simple: 
`=B1-=A1`
and then setting the cell format to `[h]:mm`

However, I've then tried to use an IF statement in a separate column to evaluate and flag if the calculated value is less than or greater than 72hrs:

```
=IF(C1<72:00:00,1,0)
```

This, and variations of it using double quotes etc hasn't worked for me.

I guess the problem is because the calculated value in column C is still in datetime format. Can anyone please advise the correct syntax to make the IF statement work?

Comment: I don't recommend it but just for info, this works `=IF(C1<"72:00"+0,1,0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel is actually pretty friendly in this regard.  The key is that date/time and differences are reported as decimals - the whole portion being the number of days, the decimal, being the fractional days (hours/minutes).

So - for your example - after doing the subtraction, you should flag that particular field with =C1 < 3 ==> TRUE (if less than 72 hours), FALSE (otherwise)

Hope that helps,
- John

Comment: Thanks @John, that's sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(C1<3,1,0)`

72 hours is just the number 3 in Excel Date-Time syntax